# SharePoint Online - Custom forms to Modern List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience

Can we have a customized forms (New/Edit/Display) on Modern List? When I click on NewItem/EditItem the customized form should open at the center of the page instead of Right side.
Is it feasible to achieve this or not? if yes, appreciate if someone can provide a bare minimum sample or detailed steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid that is not possible since there is no `ListFormWebPart` in modern experience.

You can see the supported customization in modern list form via this document: [Customizing "modern" lists and libraries.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries#overview-of-customization-options)

Related discussion: [Can we center the Power Apps form like we do on InfoPath form?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-we-center-the-Power-Apps-form-like-we-do-on-InfoPath-form/td-p/405702)

Comment: ok.. Atleast can I have custom button on the ribbon ideally next to New Item and upon clicking on the button can I open a WebPart as a model popup? if yes, can I have link on each list item upon clicking open the same WebPart with edit functionality?

Comment: @san No, that’s not supported in modern experience either: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-on-modern-team-sites. If you want to add buttons for redirection or not open the edit form from right side, you will need to add the link on another site page instead of using the default list form, which will open the list form on a separate page.

Comment: Can't it be done through ListView Extensions? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api.

Comment: @san The extension allows you to add additional actions like custom alert in lists. It does not change the layout or create a new list form for you.

Comment: I am not looking for layout change.. with Custom Command Button Set (New and Edit buttons).. I am thinking of adding my own html and display it through custom dialog with save button. Will this work or can there be any unforeseen blockers? see this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx.. can I replace color picker with some custom form layout with Save Button?

Comment: @san Using custom HTML might work, yes, you are right. The extension does allow you to do that.